# What's the proper way to style a page ? Create snippets of CSS and add corresponding classes to the HTML tags, or use CSS selectors/IDs to style?

Tags: css

Let me illustrate. Consider this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title_div">
        <h2>This title has style</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="content_div">
        <h2>This is not styled.</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Let's say I want to style the first `h2` in my CSS stylesheet.

Which way is better ?

**1:**

```
redtext{
    color: red;
}

italictext{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

And then add the following attribute to the first div : `class="redtext italictext"`

Or **2:**

```
#title_div h2{
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: If  you *really* had to choose, everyone should pick **2**, because 1 is invalid CSS (no `id` or `class` identified).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Well, I believe that is situational. Ideally it should be whatever produces the least amount of code and least amount of HTML classes. So use the CSS selectors wisely and to your benefit instead of separating each rule to its own class. If you are concerned about reusability and separation of "structure from skin" then have a look at [OOCSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/).

Answer (score 0):

Personal but I would go for (if you need a uniform `H2` through the site)

```
h2
{
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

but the for you may need to integrate the other option for more custom parts of the site if you would like different `H2` styles through the site.

However have you coincided using SASS sounds like it may be the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use example #2 or change your html to by removing the surrounding div tag. The surrounding div tag seems to only be there to have a class.

```
<h2 class="title">This title has a style</h2>
```

And your css to

```
.title{
color: red;
font-style: italic;
}
```

The content `<h2>` should probably be an `<h3>` not an `<h2>` to keep the document structure clean.